# XPath All A within a TD which also contains an H3 with the innertext of "Directs"

Tags: .net, xml, dom, xpath, html-agility-pack

I'm scraping a website. There's a TD where the first child node is an H3 with an innertext of "Directs". In the TD the other children (besides the H3) are the links. I know XPath is perfectly capable of just returning the A tag children from a TD that also contains an H3 with an innertext of "Directs", I just can't seem to get it right. The ugly work-around I came up with is the following, but I want to learn the best XPath method:

```
For Each thisH3 As HtmlNode In Doc.SelectNodes("//h3")
    If thisH3.InnerText = "Directs" Then
        For Each nChild As HtmlNode In thisH3.ParentNode.ChildNodes
            If nChild.Name = "a" Then
                Debug.Print(nChild.InnerText)
            End If
        Next
    End If
Next
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this XPath to retrieve all `a` in `td` which have `h3` with value `Directs`:

```
//td[h3 = 'Directs']/a
```

Comment: If your `<a>` might be enclosed in other markup in the TD, you would want another slash in there: `//td[h3 = 'Directs']//a`

Comment: The `A`s are direct children of the `TD`, but that's good information thanks @Phrogz